# Scrollview below toolbar in android

Tags: android, android-scrollview

Is it possible to set scrollbar below a toolbar in Android? I am trying out the scrollbarView I have toolbar attached to my Layout something like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/layoutcolor_background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription,RtlHardcoded,NestedWeights">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/main_toolbar" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/toolbar_dropshadow" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/aandcID"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight=".50"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/alayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:layout_weight=".50"
                android:background="@color/layoutbackgroudforrow"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/aimage"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/acc" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/aType"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/aimage"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="Deposit"
                    android:textColor="@color/blackText"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry,RtlHardcoded,HardcodedText" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/anumber"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/aType"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="12345678901234567890"
                    android:textColor="@color/blackText"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry,RtlHardcoded,HardcodedText" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/rupeeIcon"
                    android:layout_width="12dp"
                    android:layout_height="14dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/anumber"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/accatext"
                    android:background="@drawable/rupees_symbol"
                    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/accatext"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/anumber"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="09876543210987654321"
                    android:textColor="@color/numbertext"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry,RtlHardcoded,HardcodedText" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/footer_band" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

With the above code.. Toolbar is also scrolled and hence it get cut too. Is there a way freeze toolbar and then scroll other views.

It would be great if somebody could guide me?

Thanks!

Comment: keep scrollview and toolbar as child of relative layout. give alignparenttop=true to toolbar.

Comment: If I do as child then scrollview can host only one direct child

Comment: Can you please explain what to do with an example? Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just do something like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

           <!-- Rest of your content -->

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: But the scrollview will not scroll below toolbar, it will always start below of toolbar, as it is the second child of verticle linear layout.

Answer (score 3):

Just put the Toolbar above the ScrollView, and then, add then add the layout_below parameter in the ScrollView, so you make sure it appears under the Toolbar.

It definitely works.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ads = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools = "http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior = "@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn = "@layout/category_layout">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
```